# Using Bluetooth Stylus designed for iOS on Windows PCs

Tags: ios, windows, bluetooth-lowenergy, stylus-pen

The Problem:

Many touchscreens used on PCs/laptops with Windows 8 have multitouch capability, but no digitizer to convey stylus pressure data. The current, popular solution is to use Bluetooth on the stylus to stream the pressure data and combine that with the touch information. Sadly, after scouring the internet, I've found that pretty much all of these types of stylus' are designed to function with iOS or Android devices, for example:

- Jot Touch Pro: http://www.adonit.net/jot/touch/
- Pencil: http://www.fiftythree.com/pencil

etc...

The Question(s):

1. Is it possible to sync one of these iOS/Android stylus' with a PC and be able to view the data stream from the device? Would this data be useful (not encrypted or proprietary)?
2. What would be involved in creating some sort of interface/driver so that the stylus could be used in a drawing application? Am I crazy for even attempting something like this without building my own hardware?

I really just want to get an idea of the scope of a project like this before I attempt anything crazy. I would be extremely grateful for any help provided.